# Not like operation on a table

Tags: sql

I have two tables something like:

```
CID | EmpId | EmailId
=========================
10 | 101 | rb@gmail.com
11 | 102 | gm@yopmail.com
12 | 103 | tm@toymail.com
```

and:

```
DID | DomainList
==================
1001 | yopmail.com
1002 | toymail.com
```

I want to fetch records from table 1, where the EmailId domain, does not contain domains from table 2.

Results should be something like:

```
CID | EmpId | EmailId
=========================
10 | 101 | rb@gmail.com
```

Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged Oracle and SQL Server? Any reason?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Based oh your previous question I am assuming Oracle. Please don't tag any un-related RDBMS.

Comment: Tag the only DBMS that you are really using.

Comment: You haven't even asked a question. Please come here **after** you tried to solve a task yourself. Show us how far you have come and explain the issues with your solution. Don't have us write queries for you, just because you find it too tedious to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` might help; sample data first, query you need begins at line #13.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  ta (cid, empid, emailid) as
  4    (select 10, 101, 'rb@gmail.com'   from dual union all
  5     select 11, 102, 'gm@yopmail.com' from dual union all
  6     select 12, 103, 'tm@toymail.com' from dual
  7    ),
  8  tb (did, domainlist) as
  9    (select 1001, 'yopmail.com' from dual union all
 10     select 1002, 'toymail.com' from dual
 11    )
 12  -- query that might help
 13  select ta.*
 14  from ta
 15  where not exists (select null from tb
 16                    where substr(ta.emailid, instr(ta.emailid, '@') + 1) = tb.domainlist);

       CID      EMPID EMAILID
---------- ---------- --------------
        10        101 rb@gmail.com

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` in SQL Server (Previously tagged) :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from domain dmn where dmn.DomainList = stuff(t.EmailId, 1, charindex('@', t.EmailId), ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` . . . in either SQL Server or Oracle:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from domain d
                  where t.email like concat('%@', d.DomainList)
                 );
```